# Clob column java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Tags: java, oracle, sqlexception

```
insertSQL = "insert into TELBP_INPUT_LOG (SERIAL_NO, INPUT_XML) values (?, ?)";
statement = connection.prepareStatement(insertSQL);
statement.setString(1, serialNo);
statement.setString(2, inXml);          
//statement.setString(2, "test");
insertCount = statement.executeUpdate();
```

when the program run to executeUpdate(), error

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
```

is thrown, but if I copy the value of serialNO and inXml and run in SQL developer, no error prompted, what is the reason?

oracle version:Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi
column:
SERIAL_NO  VARCHAR2(22)
INPUT_XML  CLOB
Websphere:Websphere 5.1
jdbc: both ojdbc14 and ojdbc6 is tried, both has same error

Comment: What column types are SERIAL_NO and INPUT_XML?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot write a String into a Clob column.

Instead of

```
statement.setString(2, inXml);
```

use

```
statement.setClob(2, xmlClob);
```

You first need to create xmlClob:

```
Clob xmlClob = connection.createClob();
Writer clobWriter = myClob.setCharacterStream(1);
clobWriter.write(inXml);
```

Comment: createClob() is java 1.6 API, I am just using java 1.4, so any other method?  
and one more information, in another server environment using websphere 7 and java 1.6 and using the same code (setString()), it has no any error!! why?

Comment: I've been trying to find 1.4 Javadoc online but it's so old now I can't find any. If it really doesn't have a setClob() method, you might need to use an Oracle-specific API. As for 1.6, it's possible that this newer version automatically converts Strings to Clobs for you.

Comment: ((oracle.jdbc.OracleResultSet) resultSet).getCLOB("clob_column");
Writer writer = clob.getCharacterOutputStream();
writer.write(toStore.toCharArray());
writer.flush();
writer.close();

Answer (score 1):

for `clob` field you can make use of .`setClob(..)`

```
setString():Sets the designated parameter to the given Java String value. The driver converts this to an SQL VARCHAR or LONGVARCHAR value (depending on the argument's size relative to the driver's limits on VARCHAR values) when it sends it to the database.
```

[API DOC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString%28int,%20java.lang.String%29)

[CLOB API DOC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setClob%28int,%20java.io.Reader%29)

Answer (score 1):

Java (the underlying driver) treats CLOB as a character stream. When ever you are setting String, the underlying driver implementation will automatically do the relevant conversion (String to Varchar etc.,).  As CLOB is a special type, it is the responsibility of the programmer to do the necessary steps.  Follow the link to now how to insert clob using java:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html